# Django request.user.has_perm('aaa.add_cust')

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hello I am so confused and new to Django.
I keep getting "False" returned to me when checking user permission. but when I print the results it is clearly detects the user permission. I am trying to add a @permission_required decorator to the view but I just won't work.
#@permission_required('aaa.add_cust',raise_exception=True)

view.py

```
def permtest_view(request):
user_name = request.user
user_perm = request.user.get_all_permissions()
user_test = request.user.has_perm('aaa.add_cust')
print(user_name,user_perm,user_test)
```

Models.py

```
class cust(models.Model):
    cust = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Serializer

```
class cust_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = cust
    fileds = "__all__"
```

output of the print statement.
test1@test1.com {'aaa.add_cust'} False

I can get the user and the perm but when I do
user_test = request.user.has_perm('aaa.add_cust')
I get "False" back every time

I rely don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: There is some rows in database "user permissons" table ?

Comment: yes, I added the user to the permission in the Admin panel. But for some reason I can not use @permission_required it returns "False".
Request.user.has-perm('aaa.add_cust') returns "False" 
request.get_all_permissions returns "add_cust". So I am really confessed why permission_required is not returning True.I can add the line to test the permission but In my opinion I should not have to . plus if there is something broken I want to fix it properly in case it bites me later down the road

Comment: this statement returns "True" 
user_test2 = user_name.has_module_perms('aaa.add_cust')

Comment: Maybe you are unathorize ? (not logged in)

Comment: That is a good Question. I am using Postman and a Auth "token". Technicaly the user is not logged in through DJango's site. Interesting situation. 
If a user is sending the key through to the rest-API dose this mean he is "Not" logged in? 
I will run a quick test. I will try logging in the user though the admin page in Django. Then send the request through postman.

Comment: No difference. I think the only way around this is to build my own decorator.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it working by building my own custom decorator. still bugging me why the default Django one does not work. The good thing that cam from this is a think I have a way better customised decorator that I will be able to use going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I built my own customised Decorator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).